# Merge en Python igualando varias variables

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero unir dos tablas mediante merge, igualando 3 variables comunes en ambas tablas.

- df1:

```
     job         marital month valor
    unemployed   married june   7
    entrepreneur married august 9
```

- df2:

```
     job         marital month valor1
    unemployed   married june   10
    entrepreneur married august 15
```

Estoy usando esto:

```
    df_nuevo=pd.merge(df1, df2, on='month' and 'marital' and 'job', how='left')
```

Y me gustaría que saliera:

- df_nuevo:

```
     job         marital month valor valor1
    unemployed   married june   7    10
    entrepreneur married august 9    15
```

Pero sólo en el nuevo df sólo se iguale a través de job, y se multiplican los registros.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: faltan datos: ¿qué contiene cada tabla? Si estás usando Pandas como parece, dale a [edit] y añade la etiqueta correspondiente así como una explicación detallada según lo indicado en [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no pasas correctamente las columnas al argumento on:

```
on='month' and 'marital' and 'job'
```

evalúa `'month' and 'marital' and 'job'`, como todas las cadenas contienen algo se evalúan como verdaderas todas, el resultado es:

`on = True and True and True` -> `on = True`

Debes pasar un iterable con los nombres de las columnas, por ejemplo una tupla:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({"job": ("unemployed", "entrepreneur"),
                    "marital": ("married", "married"),
                    "month": ("june", "august"),
                    "valor": (7, 9)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"job": ("unemployed", "entrepreneur"),
                    "marital": ("married", "married"),
                    "month": ("june", "august"),
                    "valor1": (10, 15)})

df_nuevo=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=('month', 'marital', 'job'), how='left')
```

> ```
> >>> df1
>             job  marital   month  valor
> 0    unemployed  married    june      7
> 1  entrepreneur  married  august      9
>
> >>> df2
>             job  marital   month  valor1
> 0    unemployed  married    june      10
> 1  entrepreneur  married  august      15
>
> >>> df_nuevo
>             job  marital   month  valor  valor1
> 0    unemployed  married    june      7      10
> 1  entrepreneur  married  august      9      15
> ```